# Simplify table with repeated entries MYSQL

Tags: mysql, union, rows

I have created a table as a union of two SELECT statements, say FRIENDS_AND_NEIGHBORS, and I want to remove the repetitions of the two, except that they do not coincide in all the fields.

Simplifying my case, I have a table called FRIENDS (that has pairs of users, and its link id) and a table for USER that includes ZIP_CODE, from which I get the NEIGHBORS section. I'm also fixing a reference user with `USER_ID = @usr`, and `ZIP_CODE = @zip`.  Then I do the following.

```
CREATE TABLE FRIENDS_AND_NEIGHBORS
(SELECT 
    USER_ID   AS FRND_ID,    # Choose neighbors by zipcode. 
    ZIP_CODE  AS FRND_ZIP,   # 
    0         AS FRND_LINK   # The reference for friendship comes later.
FROM USER
WHERE ZIP_CODE = @zip)
UNION
(SELECT
    frd.FRIEND_ID AS FRND_ID, 
    usr.ZIP_CODE  AS FRND_ZIP, 
    frd.LINK      AS FRND_LINK
FROM FRIENDS frd
JOIN USER usr
  ON frd.FRIEND_ID = usr.USER_ID
WHERE frd.USER_ID = @usr);
```

Then I may be counting some neighbor/friends twice, but they still differ in the `FRND_LINK`
 column, as I gave it a zero because I couldn't join the two.
I want to remove the corresponding neighbor row that has 0, when it has been counted as a friend.

Thank you for your help.